# How to define the column order QSqlTableModel

Tags: qt, pyqt

I'm trying to display some data from the database in a table with the possibility to edit the data, using Qt (more specific, PyQT). A QSqlTableModel can be used for this. But with a QSqlTableModel is is not possible to easily reorder the columns, or maybe exclude a column.

I know it is possible to move columns using QSqlTableModel.horizontalHeader.moveSection but this function depends on the index of the columns, and that is not really convenient, especially if I want to add another column in the future.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easiest way to re-order the columns is to change the order of the columns in your SQL statement. If you want a more dynamic way of doing this, you'll have to move them around with moveSection, as you said.

Comment: this Link might help:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/42892-QSqlTableModel-remove-column-by-name